# Getting data periodically from PostgreSQL and sent it to ActiveMQ

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, activemq-classic

Basically, i've a data table in PostgreSQL.
I want to get all the data, and sent it become message to ActiveMQ (1 message for 1 row in table).

But the data table automatically updated every 5 second. So there is some new data in table for every 5 second.

How to sending the new data without double sending the data that was sent?
And i think i must use the Thread.sleep(5000) for made it endless looping?

This all i got:

```
package testcode;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;


public class ProducerClear2 {

    public static String vardbserver;
    public static String vardbuser;
    public static String vardbpassword;
    public static String vardbname;

    public static void main (String[] args){
        vardbserver = "TestDBtoMQ";
        vardbuser = "postgresql";
        vardbpassword = "admin";

        ConnectionFactory factory = null;
        javax.jms.Connection connection = null;
        Session session = null;
        Destination destination = null;
        MessageProducer producer = null;
        Connection c = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/"+vardbserver, vardbuser, vardbpassword);
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("----------------------------");

            stmt = c.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MESSAGES;");
            while (rs.next()) {
                String  message = rs.getString("MESSAGE");
                System.out.println("Message = " + message);
                try {
                    factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
                    connection = factory.createConnection();
                    connection.start();
                    session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                    destination = session.createQueue("TestQueue");
                    producer = session.createProducer(destination);
                    TextMessage mssg = session.createTextMessage(message);
                    System.out.println("Sent: " + mssg.getText());
                    producer.send(mssg);
                }
                catch (JMSException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            c.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage());
        }finally {
            if (session != null) {
                try {
                    session.close();
                } catch (JMSException ex) {
                    // ignore
                }
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (JMSException ex) {
                    // ignore
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("Message sent successfully");
    }
}
```

**The answer check [here](https://gist.github.com/kejiro/bb8c7da5ee36a8bc447c0104208f5902)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fetch only the new data from postgres, you can use the xmin system column on each row that stores the transaction id for that particular row.

```
select xmin::varchar::bigint as xrow, * from messages;
```

Then you can keep track of the last transaction fetched so next time you run the query you can use that value as a limit

```
select xmin::varchar::bigint as xrow, * from messages 
    where xmin::varchar::bigint > :last_transaction_id_from_previous_run;
```

If you are using postgres 9.4 or newer, you have also the possibility to use logical replication in order to stream data directly from the database.

For more information about the logical replication: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/logicaldecoding.html

#### Update:

The sample code in the question can be rewritten like this, I excluded everything outside the first `try` statement for brevity

```
// Moved all the setup for the ActiveMQ connection outside the loops
// Otherwise they would create a new connection/sessions for each iteration without being closed
factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
connection = factory.createConnection();
connection.start();
session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
destination = session.createQueue("TestQueue");
producer = session.createProducer(destination);

Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
System.out.println("----------------------------");

// Made a try-with-resources block in order to auto close everything in case of failure, no need to remember to close them manually.
// Using prepared statements so that the query itself doesn't have to be parsed for each iteration
try (Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/" + vardbserver, vardbuser, vardbpassword);
     PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MESSAGES where xmin::varchar::bigint > ? and xmin::varchar::bigint < ? ");
     PreparedStatement max = c.prepareStatement("select max(xmin::varchar::bigint) as txid from messages")
) {
    c.setAutoCommit(false);

    // Keep track of the previous and next transaction id in order to provide windowed results
    Long previousTxId = 0L;
    Long nextTxId = 0L;

    while (true) { // Enter an infinite loop
        stmt.clearParameters(); // Remove any set parameters in the fetch query

        // Fetch the next transaction id by executing the prepared statement in max
        try (ResultSet rs = max.executeQuery()) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                nextTxId = rs.getLong(1);
            }
        }

        // Set the window in the messages query. 
        // Since the query has already been prepared, we only need to set the parameters
        stmt.setLong(1, previousTxId);
        stmt.setLong(2, nextTxId + 1);

        // Execute the statment fetching all messages that were created between previousTxId and nextTxId
        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                String message = rs.getString("MESSAGE");
                System.out.println("Message = " + message);
                TextMessage mssg = session.createTextMessage(message);
                System.out.println("Sent: " + mssg.getText());
                producer.send(mssg);
            }
            // Update previousTxId for the next iteration
            previousTxId = nextTxId; 
        }
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: thankyou for suggesting, i'll makes the code endless loop btw...
its possible right?

Comment: As long as you update the placeholder `:last_transaction_id_from_previous_run` with the last `xmin` value that you fetched, that should not be a problem. If there are no new messages, then xmin will not change, and you will not receive any new rows (since there are none).
Might cause some load on the database running it all the time though, but not more than fetching all the messages in an endless loop.

Comment: Hmmm okokk... so, from my code above, where should i put the select xmin::varchar::bigint as xrow, * from messages ? and i should loop it normally with Thread.sleep() ?

Comment: Have a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/kejiro/bb8c7da5ee36a8bc447c0104208f5902 . It shows one way to do it, and I also removed some memory leaks for you.

Comment: Thankyou! thats really help me!

Comment: Dear Jimmy, i've updated my code above... can u pls fix it become like the cote that u gave on github? i got confused fixing it lol...

Comment: I've added the gist to the answer with a bit more comments this time. Hopefully it will make it a bit more clearer how you should do

Comment: Ah sorry i got it... just need to add + vardbname +; lol...
TY btw!

Comment: Dear Jimmy, why ur looping code not working again? Yesterday i tried it works, but now it not work as before, it only stuck and when i adding new data to the database it still stuck...

Answer (score 2):

To prevent duplicated messages, there are some possible ways such as:

1. ActiveMQ supports [dupplicated message detection](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/1.0.0/duplicate-detection.html) and you can leverage this feature.
2. Use a field(bool) to denote that the row is sent or not.

Regarding the 5 seconds, you can sleep or use a scheduler to do that, for example: [Spring Scheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html), [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)

Comment: i mean, can i getting only the new comer data? it's possible if the message will be "same". Just like using timestamp to make it doesnt sending the data that was been sent before... So i guess i cant use the ActiveMQ duplicated message detection, bcs the message may will completely same, am i wrong?

Comment: How about using key properties for dupplicated message detection? You can even use primary key